# Counting Unique Items in a Single Category Using SAS SQL

Tags: sql, sas, aggregate-functions, data-analysis

I'm working on a data analysis problem using SAS, where I have a dataset consisting of various items that belong to different categories. Each item can belong to multiple categories, but I'm interested in counting the number of items that are exclusively associated with a single category. The dataset has two main columns: category_code and item_id, housed in a table named item_categories.

SAS SQL is being used to connect to Hadoop.

Objective:

My aim is to find out how many items belong strictly to one category based on the first character of the category_code (e.g., items with codes A123 and A456 are counted under category A). Items that belong to multiple categories should not be counted in the final tally (such as if it is in category A123 and B456). I am counting the items and not the categories it belongs to. If an item is in category A123 and A456, that counts as 1. If it belongs to C789 and D567, that doesn't count since the categories are different.

Challenges:

Extracting the first character of the category_code to identify the item's category.
Counting each item once, even if it's listed multiple times under the same category.
Excluding items that are listed under multiple categories from the final count.

I'm contemplating a solution that might require multiple steps in SAS SQL, but I'm not certain how to structure the queries to:

First, filter out items that belong exclusively to one category.
Then, count those items for each category.
I'm fairly new to SQL and would appreciate guidance on how to approach this problem, whether through a single sophisticated query or a series of steps.

Comment: Did you try to do it?  What happened?  Can you provide a small example set of data that can be used to demonstrate what you are trying to do?  You probably only need 2 or 3 variables and 10 or so observations to demonstrate what you are talking about.  Show the result you want for that example input.

Comment: Looks like something along the lines of `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category_code) = 1` but seeing sample data, expected results and your attempt would help immensely.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to aggregate an aggregating sub-squery.

Here is some SAS code that demonstrates the progression of thinking.  The HADOOP library engine may not be able to automatically 'in-the-background' translate SAS SQL statements into HADOOP side SQL statements, in which case you will want to ask this question to the HADOOP experts.

Example:

```
* Create sample data containing some devoted items ;
* A devoted item is associated with a single category group ;
* A category group is the first letter of the categoryid value ;

* libname source hadoop ... ;

libname source "%sysfunc(pathname(WORK))";

data source.have (keep=itemid categoryid);
  call streaminit(20240218);
  do itemid = 1 to 2**13 ;
    do count = 1 to rand('integer',2,8);
      length categoryid $4;
      categoryid = cats(byte(rand('integer',26) + 64), rand('integer', 100,999));
      output;
    end ;
  end ;
run;

proc sql ;
  create table want1(label="Items in one category group") as
  select itemid
  , categoryid
  , substr(categoryid,1,1) as cgroup length =1
  , count(distinct categoryid) as item_cgroup_instance_count
  from source.have
  group by itemid
  having count(distinct substr(categoryid,1,1)) = 1
  order by cgroup, categoryid
  ;

  create table want2(label="Items in one category group") as
  select distinct itemid
  , substr(categoryid,1,1) as cgroup length=1
  from source.have
  group by itemid
  having count(distinct substr(categoryid,1,1)) = 1
  order by cgroup, itemid
  ;

  create table want3(label="Counts of items soley in one category group") as
  select 
    cgroup
  , count(distinct itemid) as devoted_item_count
  from  
    (   select
          itemid
        , substr(categoryid,1,1) as cgroup length=1
        from source.have
        group by itemid
        having count(distinct substr(categoryid,1,1)) = 1
    )
  group by
    cgroup 
  ;
quit;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't run. The error was on "having count(distinct substr(categoryid,1,1)) = 1". It results in an invalid column reference error '1' in Hive.

Comment: Did you at least use "category_code" instead of "categoryid" ?